# i have 20 modules in single ear file but using log4j2.xml i want it to be specific to each and every war

Tags: log4j2

i have one ear with 20 modules and each module has the respective log4j2.xml file for example for module A its a-log4j2.xml for module B its b-log4j2.xml likewise there are 20 different log4j2.xml file respect to each war and i have defined the entry of log4j2.xml file  in web.xml of respective war .how can i able to get the log in the respective module war.how can i change the logging context when the context is changed in the ear with respect to module.Please someone help on same . I am able to see log entries of all module sin one log file which is getting picked up by logging framework at first .

Comment: is there someone who can help on this

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the question. I understand you have 20 war files in an ear, each with their own log4j2.xml, but the rest is unclear.